# Wordpress pagination system

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a problem with my pagination system (wordpress). It's on my search page (display results), currently, the search system include only 2 post types, and the search system works fine, but clearly impossible to create a pagination system. I just want to create a simple previous and next page nav with the number of the current page.

```
<div class="contenu cont-menu fixed-cont aff">
<div class="page p-spe">Résults : 
<span class="blue"><?php the_search_query(); ?></span></div>
<div class="nombre"><?php global $wp_query; echo ' ' .    
$wp_query->found_posts . ' Result(s)'; ?></div>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="article-menu">

<div class="article-menu a-m-sp">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<span class="rollover r2"> </span>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(226,150)); ?>
</a>
<div class="right p-special">
<h2 class="h2-article-menu h2-ma"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="date"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></p>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="sl8">Know more</a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="sep sp-s"> </div>

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<nav class="nav-pages">
<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?>
<span class="nombre-pages"><?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo $paged.' / '.$wp_query->max_num_pages;
?></span>
<?php next_posts_link('Next &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>

<?php else : ?>

<div class="aucun-resultat">

<?php _e( 'No results' ); ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

So i add the pages nav just after the endwhile of the search results. I don't know why my system doesn't work. I'm a wordpress beginner, thank you for your help. Bernard

Comment: Something like [this?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545)

Comment: Hi Pieter, why not, but I think It's possible to make something easier and more simple. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom query for this. Just add `paginate_links()` which generates pagination with arrows and numbers (can be configured to display as you wish).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Answer (score 0):

I update my post, because I made a pagination for 1 post type and It works fine. But now I would like to do a pagination of 2 post types. How i can change this code to make it works ?

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=4&post_type=dossiers'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
```